# "List-style-type decimal" giving bullet points not numbering

Tags: html, css, web

I have some code that I'm trying to use to mimic a `blockquote` tag in the style for my HTML in a certain instance.

In CSS-speak this instance is `div.source ol li` , and the CSS on my page is as follows ([my site](http://biochemistri.es))

```
blockquote div {
    line-height:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
blockquote div p {
    line-height:1em;
}
div.source > p:first-child {
    display:inline;
}
div.source blockquote {
    margin-top:.9em;
}
div.source ol li {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
div.source ol {
    font-family:SEGOEUIL;
    line-height:1;
    margin-top:.9em;
    font-size:130%;
    display:block;
    -webkit-margin-before:0;
    -webkit-margin-after:0;
    -webkit-margin-start:0;
    -webkit-margin-end:0;
    background-color:0 color-stop(50%, #E0F8E0), color-stop(51%, #E6F8E0), color-stop(100%, #F5FBEF));
    background:0;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0;
    padding:0 .9em;
}
blockquote {
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:SEGOEUIL;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1;
    padding-top:0;
}
body {
    font-size:70%;
    line-height:1.4;
    margin:0;
}
blockquote p, div.source ol p {
    -webkit-margin-before:0;
    -webkit-margin-after:0;
}
# blockquote p sub, div.source ol p sub {
    margin-top:-15px;
}
```

As you might be able to see, `div.source ol` behaves as if it was `blockquote` as far as formatting is concerned, however the `<li>` tag is rendering as a bullet point, and when I inspect the element it says `list-style-type:decimal` as it should be... Can anyone explain?

**EDIT** This is with `list-style-position:inside` as recommended by Explosion Pills
[image]

**EDIT 2** Still can only indent the first line...! http://jsfiddle.net/a6Dfh/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it's not a bullet point but the period of the decimal.  The issue is that you have `list-style-position: outside` (the default), but the `<ol>` is contained by an element with `overflow: hidden` so you can't actually see the decimals.  Try adding more padding to the `<ol>` or change it to `list-style-position: inside`, or both, to move the numbers around until they fit where you want them.

Comment: Ah I see, I've put list-style-position:inside and it makes it appear as in the picture (see edit to question) - can I get it onto a single line somehow with padding? And I'm assuming padding-left?

Comment: The `<p>` wrapper is forcing the content to move to a new line

Comment: this thing refuses to play ball ! padding 20 px is just indenting the first line http://jsfiddle.net/a6Dfh/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should apply the `list-style-type` to the `ul` or `ol` as opposed to the list items.

Here is the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).